# How can I use Serilog to log the length of content received, execution time, and results of SignalR hub methods?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, serilog

I want to log certain information in SignalR using Serilog, similar to what is obtained with UseSerilogRequestLogging.

I've tried using HubLogFilter to solve my problem, but I'm unable to capture the length of content received, execution time, and execution results.

Here is my current code

```
public class HubLogFilter : IHubFilter
{
    ILogger<HubLogFilter> logger;

    public HubLogFilter(ILogger<HubLogFilter> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async ValueTask<object?> InvokeMethodAsync(
        HubInvocationContext invocationContext,
        Func<HubInvocationContext, ValueTask<object?>> next
    )
    {
        try
        {
            var context = invocationContext.Context.GetHttpContext();
            if (context != null)
            {
                var remoteIp = context?.Request.Headers?["X-Forwarded-For"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteIp))
                {
                    remoteIp = context?.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
                }

                logger.LogInformation(
                    "WebSocket {RequestPath}/{HubMethodName} {RemoteIpAddress} {UserId}",
                    context?.Request.Path,
                    invocationContext.HubMethodName,
                    remoteIp,
                    invocationContext.Context.UserIdentifier ?? "NonUser"
                );
            }
            return await next(invocationContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError($"Exception calling '{invocationContext.HubMethodName}': {ex}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my using UseSerilogRequestLogging code.

```
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(options =>
    {
        options.MessageTemplate = "HTTP {RequestMethod} {RequestPath} {RemoteIpAddress} {ReqContentLength} {UserID} responded {StatusCode} in {Elapsed:0.0000} ms";

        options.EnrichDiagnosticContext = (diagnosticContext, httpContext) =>
        {
            diagnosticContext.Set("ReqContentLength", httpContext.Request.ContentLength);

            var remoteIp = httpContext?.Request.Headers?["X-Forwarded-For"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteIp))
            {
                remoteIp = httpContext?.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
            }
            diagnosticContext.Set("RemoteIpAddress", remoteIp);

            var userId = httpContext?.User.Identity?.GetField("user_id");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                userId = "NonUser";
            }
            diagnosticContext.Set("UserID", userId);
        };
    });
```

Can someone provide guidance on how to achieve this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have test it and you can check my test result first.

[image]

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace AspCore7_Web_Identity.ForumCase._77155626
{

    public class HubLogFilter : IHubFilter
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HubLogFilter> _logger;

        public HubLogFilter(ILogger<HubLogFilter> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async ValueTask<object?> InvokeMethodAsync(
            HubInvocationContext invocationContext,
            Func<HubInvocationContext, ValueTask<object?>> next
        )
        {
            var startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            var context = invocationContext.Context.GetHttpContext();
            var remoteIp = GetRemoteIpAddress(context);
            var userId = invocationContext.Context.UserIdentifier ?? "NonUser";

            try
            {
                var result = await next(invocationContext);

                result = "failed";
                // this means we can find the message sent from client
                if (invocationContext.HubMethodArguments.Count > 0)
                {
                    result = "succeed";
                }

                var elapsed = DateTimeOffset.Now - startTime;
                var arguments = invocationContext.HubMethodArguments;
                var contentLength = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(arguments).Length;

                //var contentLength = CalculateContentLength(invocationContext.HubMethodArguments);

                _logger.LogInformation(
                    "WebSocket {RequestPath}/{HubMethodName} {RemoteIpAddress} {UserId} executed in {Elapsed:0.0000} ms with content length {ContentLength}",
                    context?.Request.Path,
                    invocationContext.HubMethodName,
                    remoteIp,
                    userId,
                    elapsed.TotalMilliseconds,
                    contentLength
                );

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Exception calling '{invocationContext.HubMethodName}': {ex}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static string GetRemoteIpAddress(HttpContext? context)
        {
            var remoteIp = context?.Request.Headers?["X-Forwarded-For"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteIp))
            {
                remoteIp = context?.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
            }

            return remoteIp ?? "Unknown";
        }

        private static int CalculateContentLength(object?[] arguments)
        {
            var serializedArgs = JsonSerializer.Serialize(arguments);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(serializedArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesone, it's work, Thanks your help!