# How the ASP.NET application can tracking websocket traffic?

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

For a web application I'm working on, I need to measure the internet traffic that is used by web sockets (both incoming and outgoing traffic). I am using .NET 6 and ASP.NET Core SignalR, the service is deployed via K8S. I don’t need a lot of detail about the traffic used for a specific connection; I need general information for a day. I'm going to collect statistics on traffic consumption through Prometheus.

I have no experience in solving similar problems, so I have no idea which way to look. The search for ready-made solutions did not yield results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, each http request will trigger the middleware mentioned by [geldek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11284068/geldek), but websocket requests will not trigger the middleware.

We should use Hub Filter to implement it. For more details, [you can check the sample code I test before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77157545/7687666), It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0). When the request arrives, you can inspect it and calculate the size (whatever that means for your purposes).