# How to configure WebSocket for SignalR for successful response in listener? How to capture messages from developer console using WebSocket samplers?

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

The requirement is to capture "Success" message from developer console tab which uses SignalR.

Web socket samplers are not capturing any data from console nor its showing any response in View result tree.

We have implemented below web socket samplers with necessary information (Server IP/ Port no/Path etc) :-

1. Web socket open connection
2. WebSocket request-response Sampler
3. WebSocket Single Read Sampler
4. WebSocket Single Write Sampler

But not able to see any responses for web socket in View result tree.

Rest everything is working as expected.

Comment: What the SignalR mean in this post ? [Asp.net core signalr ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: Yes This is Asp.net signalR

Comment: Asp.net signalR and Asp.net core signalr are different, please check your package name or project to confirm it.

Comment: We are using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR

Comment: Could you kindly check this thread, [How the ASP.NET Core application can tracking websocket traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77329961/how-the-asp-net-application-can-tracking-websocket-traffic/77342386#77342386), I also provided test code , you can click the link in my answer.

Comment: Hi Ketki, I'm not sure what your WebSocket samplers are? But I'm providing a solution where you can capture every websocket request at the application level.