# How does the rate limiting middleware limit to the hub method?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, middleware

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting;
using System.Threading.RateLimiting;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRateLimiter(_ => _
    .AddFixedWindowLimiter(policyName: "fixed", options =>
    {
        options.PermitLimit = 4;
        options.Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12);
        options.QueueProcessingOrder = QueueProcessingOrder.OldestFirst;
        options.QueueLimit = 2;
    }));

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRateLimiter();

static string GetTicks() => (DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x11111).ToString("00000");

app.MapGet("/", () => Results.Ok($"Hello {GetTicks()}"))
                           .RequireRateLimiting("fixed");

app.Run();
```

The sample code on the official website only saw the request to restrict http, and tested it to have an effect on the API, but when applied to hubmethod, it didn't work, what should I do, thank you!

After following the above configuration, I added [EnableRateLimiting("fixed")] in the corresponding method, for example:

```cs
[EnableRateLimiting("fixed")]
public Task Test()
{
   //send request
}
```

But it didn't work

Comment: As far as I can tell, 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting' works for throttling http requests, not websocket requests.

Comment: If you want to limit websocket requests, [you can try to use IHubFilter to implement it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77157545/7687666), combined with RateLimiting to limit http requests, it should be more suitable for you.

Comment: 能否给出你的示例代码呢，十分感谢

Comment: Would you mind recreating a new post with `asp.net-core-signalr` tag, as this case is too old and hasn't gotten more attention.

Comment: I will check it and give your response in your new thread.

Comment: Could you please check the comments above, if you still need help, please post a new post, many thanks.